# How to fix Error : Could not find recyclerview-v7.jar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I am new in Android. I want to use recyclerview in my project and when I implement com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0 to dependencies and build the project I got this error:

```
Could not find recyclerview-v7.jar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/28.0.0/recyclerview-v7-28.0.0.jar


Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

My build.gradle(Module:app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

and build.gradle(Myapplication):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

By the way in sdk management, android support repository is installed and my Android sdk tools is 26.1.1

any one can help me to solve this error?

Comment: Update your SDK with the latest update. current Repository version is 47

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Support Repository from SDK Tools as shown in the picture.Tick mark the checkboxes in Support Repository and install[image]